# Add a scatter plot to ggplot histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter

I would like to add a scatter plot to overlay onto my ggplot histogram in R.
On the geom_point() below it gives me an error : Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`
Could you provide guidance ?

```
rand_nr <- 10000
rand_max <- 1
rand_min <- 0
lambda <- 1
x_min <- 0
x_max <- 10
bin_nr <- 50

diff_x <- (x_max - x_min) / bin_nr
edge <- seq(x_min, x_max, diff_x)
x_var <- seq(x_min, x_max, 0.01) # actual x variable
rand_var <- runif(rand_nr, rand_min, rand_max)

X <- tan(rand_var * pi / 2) # F(X)=(2/pi)*atan(x)

p <- 1 / (1 + (x_var^2))


X_df <- data.frame(X, group = "x")
P_df <- data.frame(p, group = "p")

plot(rand_var) # plot the random variables

ggplot(X_df, aes(X, probability (x),fill=group, colour=group)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), breaks=edge, alpha=0.6, 
                 position="identity", lwd=0.2) +
  ggtitle("Normalized")
```

The working code is above. The non-working code is below

```
ggplot(X_df, aes(X, probability (x),fill=group, colour=group)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), breaks=edge, alpha=0.6, 
                 position="identity", lwd=0.2) +
  geom_point(x_var,p,aes(x1,px1)) +
  ggtitle("Normalized")
```

Comment: what is `probability(x)` supposed to do in your ggplot? I don't find any function of this name, also you are not using this aesthetic, so you could (and should) remove it, otherwise it should create undesired side effects

Comment: The probability plot was something my professor did in matlab. And I was trying to recreate it in R by simulate an approximation of the PDF with monte carlo. The answer below was the right one.

Comment: I think I may not have been clear enough - writing `aes(X, probability (x)` is probably (pun intended) not what you want. It will map the function 'probability(x)' to your y. It works here, because you are then using a `geom` that does not use y (geom_histogram) and then passing a different y to your `geom_point`. But this is pure chance. Just wanted to point out that this can cause bad bugs

Answer (score 2):

Is it what you are looking for:

```
ggplot(X_df, aes(x=X,fill=group, colour=group)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), breaks=edge, alpha=0.6, 
             position="identity", lwd=0.2) + 
    geom_point(data=P_df,aes(x = x_var,y =p)) +
  ggtitle("Normalized")
```

[image]

What has changed:

- First, since the data comes from a different dataframe, you need to add a `data=` argument in `geom_point`
- Second, as the error said, you need to provide the arguments for `x` and `y` inside of `aes`

Comment: Good catch, I had not noticed that, I removed it, thanks!