# how to combine 2 ggplot in R,

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have this code:

```
  ggplot(x) + 
   geom_histogram(aes(price, fill = ifelse(price < 150, "low", "high")),alpha = 0.85,binwidth = 15) + 
   scale_fill_manual(values = c(low = "steelblue", high = "orange")) +
   theme_minimal(base_size = 13) + xlab("Price") + ylab("Frequency") + 
   ggtitle("The Distrubition of Price")+ xlim(0,5000)
```

the result is
[image]

and I have this code

```
ggplot(x, aes(price)) + stat_ecdf(geom = "step", color = '#fd5c63', lwd = 1.2) + 
   ylab("Proportion") + xlab("Price") + theme_minimal(base_size = 13) + xlim(0,5000)+
   ggtitle("The Cumulative Distrubition of Property Price")
```

and the result is
[image]

can you help me to combine the 2 plot into one plot, Thank you

Comment: [This question might be of use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61052990/add-a-scatter-plot-to-ggplot-histogram)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the function that you are looking for is the [sec_axis()](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/line-chart-dual-Y-axis-ggplot2.html) in the ggplot2 package.

Based on the fact that you have named the y-axis `"Frequency"` I suppose that instead of the `count` statistic of `geom_histogram()` you want `stat(count) / sum(count)` statistic, i.e., the `Frequency`. As this statistic is not going to lie between [0,1] and the cumulative distribution is going to be always in that range, you have to find a way to scale one plot to the scale of the other. In this case, I choose to scale the histogram to the [0,1] range as this is easier to transform. To do so, I plot the statistic `stat(count)/max(count)` in the histogram and set the secondary axis to the proportion.

```
ggplot(x) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(x = price, y = stat(count) / max(count), 
                       fill = ifelse(price < 150, "low", "high")),
                   alpha = 0.85,binwidth = 15) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(low = "steelblue", high = "orange")) +
    scale_y_continuous(name = 'Frequency', sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = 'Proportion')) +
    theme_minimal(base_size = 13) + xlab("Price") + 
    ggtitle("The Distrubition of Price & The Cumulative Distrubition of Property Price")+ 
    stat_ecdf(aes(price), geom = "step", color = '#fd5c63', lwd = 1.2) + 
    xlim(0,500) + xlab("Price")
```

[image: two plot combined]

If you want to preserve the scale of the primary y-axis, you have to figure out how to scale the cumulative proportion to the maximum value of the `count` statistic of the `geom_histogram()` plot.